# How to check file create date and print in write output

Tags: powershell

We have a daily job which dumps .txt files from vendors and I am writing a powershell script to process the file based on file create date. For instance when the script is run on 02/10/20 it will check if the .txt files were created on 02/09/20 if not raise a flag.

```
$file = "C:\vendor\sale\vendor_a_02092020.txt"

if($file.CreationTime.Date -e [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1)) 
{
    Write-Output "The file in the path $file created on $file.CreationTime is the latest file"
}
else
{
    Write-Output "The file in the path $file created on $file.CreationTime is not the latest file"
    }
```

I am trying to print the file path and file created date in Write-Output. Currently it does not print the full file path or the file create date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another a way to print complex strings is to use [composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting). The idea is to add indexed placeholders for variables and a list of values.

If there are several variables with long names, composite formatting greatly simplifies string building. Like so,

```
Write-output ("The file in the path {0} created on {1} is not the latest file" -f `
  $f.FullName, $f.CreationTime)
```

Parenthesis are required so that a formatted string is passed to `write-output`.

As a side note, Powershell's got `Get-Date` which is more idiomatic. The functionality is equal, but I prefer Powershell-ish version over .Net style. Not that there is any difference but how the code looks.

```
# Idiomatic psh
$file.CreationTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date
# .Net -styled
$file.CreationTime.Date -eq [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1).Date
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `Get-Item` to get the file information (including full path).
- Also, if you are printing a variable with its property inside a string, you have to use `$($variable.property)` to keep the property part of the variable (instead of string).
- Comparisons are done with -eq ... not sure if that was misspelled when you copied it to SO. -le (less than or equal), -ge (greater than or equal) etc.
- If you are comparing Date of the DateTime, make sure you select Date on both sides of the equation as well.

```
$file = Get-Item "C:\vendor\sale\vendor_a_02092020.txt"

if($file.CreationTime.Date -eq [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1).Date) 
{
    Write-Output "The file in the path $(file.FullName) created on $($file.CreationTime) is the latest file"
}
else
{
    Write-Output "The file in the path $(file.FullName) created on $($file.CreationTime) is not the latest file"
}
```